# How do you barrel an NPM package with an index file at the root of the package?

Tags: typescript, npm, publish

## Questions

There is something called a "barrel", which essentially re-exports modules using an `index.ts` file with the purpose to organize imports (as far as I understand). This can be done for any folder, after which any parent (or children of the parent) folder can import by using the directory name (because `index` is implied).
When this stays internal to a project, it makes sense. E.g. importing `user.model.ts` and `user.service.ts` from `./users` when there is a `/user/index.ts`, as opposed to `./users/user.model` and `./users/user.service`.

I am now trying to understand this from the perspective of publishing a package to NPM. The goal is to be able to import directly from the package root (`import { User, UserService, Loan, LoanService } from "package"`).
Shown below is the directory structure (including build), `package.json`, `tsconfig.json`, and `npm publish --dry-run` result.
This ends up being a `dist` directory with a root `index.js` and `index.d.ts`, and a `src` folder. This means a project consuming this package can import from `package/dist`.
I have seen other projects ([Nest.js' TypeORM package](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm), for example) with transpiled `index` files at their project root and include them in the package (in this case, by adding it to the `files` array in `package.json`). I don't understand how this works, as build puts everything in `dist`. I suppose copy pasting the transpiled `index` files manually would be a possibility, but doing things manually always ends up wrong. How would one go about this?

A second point of confusion for me is the root `index.ts` file only containing `export * from "./dist"`. In my editor, this is a compiler error:  `TS2306: File 'D:/Temporary/test/dist/index.d.ts' is not a module.`. How does this work?

Massive post, thank you for reading. I appreciate your time.

## Directory structure

Also available [here](https://tree.nathanfriend.io/?s=(%27options!(%27fancy!true%7EfullPatFtrailingSlasFrootDot!true)%7EH(%27H%27dist0srcN7C75975K73973j48C85985K83983L02d.I02L02L.map6node_modules6src0742J75J73I08N2J85J83I62IGBG-lockB6README.md6IconfigB%27)%7Eversion!%271%27)*%20%2006*2index.3.service.4sN5.model.6%5Cn7loan8user9d.J*B.LonCN*292KFh!false%7EG6packageHsource!ItsJt4Kj4*LjsN0*%01NLKJIHGFCB987654320*)

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── loan
│   │   │   ├── index.d.ts
│   │   │   ├── index.js
│   │   │   ├── loan.model.d.ts
│   │   │   ├── loan.model.js
│   │   │   ├── loan.service.d.ts
│   │   │   └── loan.service.js
│   │   └── user
│   │       ├── index.d.ts
│   │       ├── index.js
│   │       ├── user.model.d.ts
│   │       ├── user.model.js
│   │       ├── user.service.d.ts
│   │       └── user.service.js
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   ├── index.js
│   └── index.js.map
├── node_modules
├── src
│   ├── loans
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   ├── loan.model.ts
│   │   └── loan.service.ts
│   └── user
│       ├── index.ts
│       ├── user.model.ts
│       └── user.service.ts
├── index.ts
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── README.md
└── tsconfig.json
```

## package.json

```json
{
  "name": "totally-unique-package-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc",
    "prepack": "npm run build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "description": "description",
  "author": {
    "name": "name",
    "email": "email"
  }
}
```

## tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  }
}
```

## npm publish --dry-run

```bash
$ npm publish --dry-run
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> totally-unique-package-name@0.0.1 prepack
> npm run build                            

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> totally-unique-package-name@0.0.1 build
> rimraf dist && tsc                     

npm notice                                                        
npm notice package: totally-unique-package-name@0.0.1             
npm notice === Tarball Contents ===                               
npm notice 0B   README.md                                         
npm notice 148B dist/index.d.ts                                   
npm notice 688B dist/index.js                                     
npm notice 108B dist/src/loan/index.d.ts                          
npm notice 308B dist/src/loan/index.js                            
npm notice 65B  dist/src/loan/loan.model.d.ts                     
npm notice 121B dist/src/loan/loan.model.js                       
npm notice 78B  dist/src/loan/loan.service.d.ts                   
npm notice 242B dist/src/loan/loan.service.js                     
npm notice 108B dist/src/user/index.d.ts                          
npm notice 308B dist/src/user/index.js                            
npm notice 65B  dist/src/user/user.model.d.ts                     
npm notice 121B dist/src/user/user.model.js                       
npm notice 78B  dist/src/user/user.service.d.ts                   
npm notice 242B dist/src/user/user.service.js                     
npm notice 409B package.json                                      
npm notice === Tarball Details ===                                
npm notice name:          totally-unique-package-name             
npm notice version:       0.0.1                                   
npm notice filename:      totally-unique-package-name-0.0.1.tgz   
npm notice package size:  1.1 kB                                  
npm notice unpacked size: 3.1 kB                                  
npm notice shasum:        f1a8965180641151e0be6ee2d906615bef4154cc
npm notice integrity:     sha512-9v9wjvaxLH314[...]o6z5bYWckBpzA==
npm notice total files:   16                                      
npm notice                                                        
npm notice Publishing to https://registry.npmjs.org/ (dry-run)    
+ totally-unique-package-name@0.0.1
```

If needed, I can provide the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, adding an `index.ts` file at the project root being outputted to the `dist` folder works for exporting from the root folder. I could not find this anywhere.

If anyone has references to documentation explaining how this works I would appreciate it.